# If $var is empty, return 404.

Tags: plugin-development, 404-error

For security reasons, to detect if somebody is manipulating `GET` parameters of the plugin I'm writing, I need to return a `404` if the security query I perform returns nothing. How can I force that? I tried with:

```
if (security($_GET['id'])) {
    [...]
} else {
    global $wp_query;
    $wp_query->set_404();
}
```

found it in other posts, but it is not working.

Comment: *where* do you try to do this? or more importantly *when*?

Answer (score 1):

I have run into the same issue that using `$wp_query->set_404();` would properly adjust the global object but not return the 404 template. So in the plugin I was writing I used the tried and tested method:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'wp_139917_force_404' );
function wp_139917_force_404(){
    global $wp_query;
    $wp_query->set_404();
    status_header(404);
    include get_404_template();
    exit;
}
```

~ modified from source: https://github.com/codearachnid/woocommerce-product-permalink/blob/master/inc/product-permalinks.php#L56

I have alse used this other format which I believe is cleaner and where appropriate should be leveraged:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'wp_139917_sanity_force_404' );
function wp_139917_sanity_force_404( $template ){
    // use your own sanity check logic to return the 404 template
    if( your_sanity_check_true_404() ) {
        global $wp_query;
        $wp_query->set_404();
        return get_404_template();
    } else {
        return $template;
    }
}
```

Comment: i can't get it to work :(

Comment: do you have a gist/repo where your code is in place? At what point are you attempting to call a 404?

Comment: the code is only in local at the moment...

i back up on a custom error page instead of a 404, don't worry...